What the garlic is that pt.2? (Plant identification help needed)
I have sown some garlic cloves in a pot (I only have a balcony, don't judge). And... something came out of the pot, but it's not garlic, and I'm very curious what it might be (action is taking place in Denmark):


I even mistook it for garlic initially, but it's completely inedible, and in fact, can barely be chewed through in any manner - the leaves are pretty tough. As far as I could tell by rummaging in the ground, there are no cloves to this beastie, and the roots seem to go quite far down. Google Lens identifies that as Chives, but I can guarantee you it's not (I actually do have chives, in a pot beside this one). In this case, you can see some actual garlic that caught on, chilling in the background, wondering what kind of neighbor is that. It definitely feels like a weed, but I still wanted to find out what it could be before it goes out.
Any educated guesses?

That looks like and could be a rush of some kind. Do the leaves feel like they're completely smooth and cylindrical? Are they hollow? Do they NOT smell like an onion/garlic? Then probably a rush, since you're ruled out chives.

Smooth and cylindrical - Yes. Hollow - yes. Smell of onion/garlic - absolutely not. Don't taste like it either. I'd say you're right on the money after googling for rush images! I'll accept the answer in a few hours. =) As a bonus question does rush bloom into anything or is a big bush of green what it maintains itself as?

I have a largish rush that never blooms, but possibly because it's only marginally happy where it lives; If I remember correctly, the blooms are rather inconspicuous. My rush comes up white in the spring and then slowly turns to green starting about eights later. It remains green until well after the first frost, so is useful in my tiny and on-its-own garden pond. You might want to keep it around to see what it does over the course of a year; they're quite maintenance-free.

As long as it doesn't kill the garlic before I get to harvest it, I have no qualms with letting it stick around.
